# List of polymorphic references

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas: User, Goal and Achievement

In the users schema, I need a list of items the user likes. An item is either an achievement or a goal.

So I need something like this:

```
User: {
  email:     { type: String },
  username:  { type: String },
  password:  { type: String },
  firstName: { type: String }
  lastName:  { type: String },
  likes:     [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Goal/Achievement' } ],
}
```

How can I reference multiple schemas in a single list of object ids?

Edit: trying to be more specific...

This is a user example:

```
{
  email: "myemail@gmail.com"
  username: "juanfuentes"
  password: "5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8"
  firstName: "Juan"
  lastName: "Fuentes"
  likes: [
    ObjectId("579bc55d57fd27f802569061"), 
    ObjectId("5797bc7a86fc997203b52acc"), 
    ObjectId("579bc4fa3fe32af302e098a1"), 
    ObjectId("57968fd0c54d7bb9058fff77")
  ]
}
```

`ObjectId("579bc55d57fd27f802569061")` belongs to a goal

`ObjectId("5797bc7a86fc997203b52acc")` belongs to an achievement

`ObjectId("579bc4fa3fe32af302e098a1")` also belongs to a goal

`ObjectId("57968fd0c54d7bb9058fff77")` belongs to an achievement

So if likes was a list of goals, I would declare it like this:

```
likes: [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Goal } ]
```

If likes was a list of achievements, I would declare it like this:

```
likes: [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Achievement' } ]
```

However, I want likes to be a list of both Goals and Achievements. And I don't know how to declare something like that.

Comment: OK. So what is your *specific* question?

Comment: How can I reference multiple schemas in a single list of object ids?

Comment: So, the object shown above is somthing like the expected output where "ref" is either "goal" or"Achievement"? What does the input look like?

Comment: The input  will be object ids, either the oid of a goal or the  oid of an achievement

Comment: Not sure how to make it more specific

Answer (score 0):

Use [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) it is an object that consist of a document id, a name of the collection where the referenced document resides and optionally a database name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are looking for a **Many-To-Many relationship** between User and Goal/Achievement.

In that case a good method is to create 2 extra schemas, in order to link your User with the Goal and Achievement tables; like so:

Extra schema 1:

```
UserLikedGoals: {
  userId:    { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  goalId:    { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Goal' },
}
```

Extra schema 2:

```
UserLikedAchievements: {
  userId:    { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  achievementId:    { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Achievement' },
}
```

You would access the liked goals/achievements of a certain user by looking for rows containing this user's id in the new schemas.